# Linker error once trying to link Webrtc to iPhone App

Tags: ios, iphone, webrtc

Linked almost everything but got a bunch of errors like:

> Undefined symbols for architecture armv7:
>   "_AVAudioSessionModeVoiceChat", referenced from:
>         webrtc::AudioDeviceIOS::InitPlayOrRecord() in libaudio_device.a(audio_device.audio_device_ios.o)

Looks like linker cannot find AVFoundation Framework
Something wrong with project settings?
Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

You need to link your app with `AVFoundation.framework`.